# histogram -- data that equal to the breakpoints

Tags: r, histogram

The default histogram bins in R are right-closed (left open) intervals, and thus data that equal to the breakpoints fall into the left bins. I wondered if I could count those data to both left and right bins (half to the left bin and half to the right bin). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have discrete values? If so then a histogram probably isn't the right tool for visualization. Histograms are for estimating the density of a continuous variable. If you do want to completely redefine a histogram, what do you really need from it. Just a table of counts in bins? A plot? What is the true output you want?

Comment: @MrFlick The values are of binomial distribution centered at 0, and I want to make a plot to show the distribution. Do you have any suggestions about the right tool to use? Thanks!

Comment: @Runner So you have a bunch of -.5 and .5 values? If not, can you edit your question to include sample data?

Comment: @MrFlick The data are too big to be put in the question. Actually I have a lot of 0 values, but they look like minus values in the current histogram (in the (-x,0] interval). I want that the two bars around 0 look symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like your bins to be defined as the interval [a,b] instead of [a,b) (see  [What does the right parameter do when creating a histogram in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648179/what-does-the-right-parameter-do-when-creating-a-histogram-in-r?rq=1)). A bin must be left or right closed otherwise a value would fall into adjacent bins.